# MonsterInsight only reports 3% of the Wordpress blog users Blog in Google Analytics 4

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

In GA4, we get only 3% of the users shown in Universal Analytics for the same time period?

Both are tracked through **Monster Analytics Version 8.10.1** free edition upon **Wordpress Version 6.1.1**.

We correctly entered the G-XXXXXXXXXX id in the setting *Manually Enter Your GA4 Measurement ID* (else I guess we would have had 0 on GA4)

Here are our settings.

[image]

Comment: You should either conduct a proper debugging of your site's front-end and network, or just delete the plugin and implement tracking properly through GTM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A month later GA4 and older Universal Analytics numbers are now well aligned. Looks like it took a few days to properly report all users.